# C MPI - Crash for no apparent reason - Program Received signal SIGSEGV

Tags: c, debugging, mpi

I am running a program in a linux cluster using MPICH2 1.0.6 (i can't actually update it to MPICH3, so i am stuck to that version) and for no apparent reason the program doesn't execute.

I compile it using `mpicc -o prog prog.c -lm` and execute with `mpiexec`

The program is an implementation of the hierarchical agglomerative clustering algorithm using the vector space model. The data collection is an `n*m` array (in the program `DOC*MAXWORDS`) which are divided into the nodes of the cluster like `PARTS=DOC/procs` so every node is responsible for `PARTS*MAXWORDS` data.

While debugging in a serial machine using gdb and ddd i get that the program has a segmentation error in a specific line of the code, where i can't find what is wrong with it. Take a look.

```
while(iterations != DOC-k){//bigLoop

    iterations++;

    x=y=-1;
    pos1=pos2=node1=node2=-1;

    for(i=0;i<PARTS;i++){//ELEGXOS MEGISTOU TOPIKA
        if(max_array[i]>x){
            x=max_array[i];
            pos1=i;  
        }
        else if(max_array[i]==x){
            pos2=i;
        } //ELEGXOS META TO LOOP GIA OMOIOTHTES
    }

    if(max_array[pos1]!=max_array[pos2]){
        for(i=0;i<PARTS;i++){
            if(max_array[i]>max_array[pos2] && i!=pos1)
                pos2=1;
        }
    }

    if(MPI_Allgather(&x,1,MPI_DOUBLE,
            n_max,1,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_COMM_WORLD) != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Allgather high valuer - error");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=0;i<procs;i++){
        if(n_max[i]>y){
           y=n_max[i];
           node1=i;
        }
        else if(n_max[i]==y){
            node2=i;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<MAXWORDS;i++){
        merger_one[i]=merger_two[i]=0;    
    }

    if(n_max[node1]==n_max[node2]){

        if(id==node1){
            for(i=0;i<MAXWORDS;i++){
                merger_one[i]=vector[node1*PARTS+pos1][i];
                last_one[i]=vector[(node1*PARTS)+texts_vectors[node1]][i];
             }
             size_one=size_of[pos1];

             nn_array[pos1]=nn_array[texts_vectors[node1]];
             max_array[pos1]=max_array[texts_vectors[node1]];
             size_of[pos1]=size_of[texts_vectors[node1]];
             texts_vectors[node1]--;
        }
        if(id==node2){
            for(i=0;i<MAXWORDS;i++){
                merger_two[i]=vector[node2*PARTS+pos2][i];
                last_two[i]=vector[(node2*PARTS)+texts_vectors[node2]][i];
            }

            j=pos2;
            pos2=pos1;
            pos1=j;

            size_two=size_of[pos2];

            nn_array[pos2]=nn_array[texts_vectors[node2]];
            max_array[pos2]=max_array[texts_vectors[node2]];
            size_of[pos2]=size_of[texts_vectors[node2]];
            texts_vectors[node2]--;
        }
    }
    else{

        node2=node1;

        if(id==node1){

            for(i=0;i<MAXWORDS;i++){

                merger_one[i]=vector[node1*PARTS+pos1][i];
                merger_two[i]=vector[node2*PARTS+pos2][i];

                last_one[i]=vector[(node1*PARTS)+texts_vectors[node1]][i];/*SIGSEV ERROR*/
                last_two[i]=vector[(node2*PARTS)+texts_vectors[node2]-1][i];

            }

            size_one=size_of[pos1];
            size_two=size_of[pos2];

            nn_array[pos1]=nn_array[texts_vectors[node1]];
            max_array[pos1]=max_array[texts_vectors[node1]];
            size_of[pos1]=size_of[texts_vectors[node1]];


            nn_array[pos2]=nn_array[texts_vectors[node2]-1];
            max_array[pos2]=max_array[texts_vectors[node2]-1];
            size_of[pos2]=size_of[texts_vectors[node2]-1];    

            texts_vectors[node1]=texts_vectors[node1]-2;
        }  
    }
    MPI_Bcast(&pos1, 1, MPI_INT,node1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&pos2, 1, MPI_INT,node2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&size_one, 1, MPI_INT,node1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&size_two, 1, MPI_INT,node2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(merger_one, MAXWORDS, MPI_INT,node1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(merger_two, MAXWORDS, MPI_INT,node2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(last_one, MAXWORDS, MPI_INT,node1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(last_two, MAXWORDS, MPI_INT,node2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Allgather(&texts_vectors,1,MPI_INT,texts_vectors,1,MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for(i=0;i<MAXWORDS;i++){
        vector[node1*PARTS+pos1][i]=last_one[i];
        vector[node2*PARTS+pos2][i]=last_two[i];
    }

    Pmanager=PARTS+1;

    for(i=0;i<procs;i++){
        if(texts_vectors[i]<Pmanager)
        Pmanager=i;
    }

    texts_vectors[Pmanager]++;



    for(i=0;i<MAXWORDS;i++){
            x=merger_one[i]*size_one;
            y=merger_two[i]*size_two;

            vector[Pmanager*PARTS+texts_vectors[Pmanager]][i]=(x+y)/(size_one + size_two);
    }

    for(i=id*PARTS; i< (id+1)*texts_vectors[id]; i++){
       for(j=0;j<procs;j++){
           for(m=j*PARTS;m<j*PARTS+texts_vectors[j];m++){
               x=0;y=0;z=0;
               for(l=0; l < MAXWORDS; l++){
                   x+=vector[i][l]*vector[m][l];
                   y+=vector[i][l]*vector[i][l];
                   z+=vector[m][l]*vector[m][l];
               }
               if(i!=m){
                   if(y!=0 && z!=0){
                       sim_matrix[i-(PARTS*id)][m] = x / (sqrt(y) * sqrt(z) );
                   }
                   else{
                       sim_matrix[i-(PARTS*id)][m] = 0.0;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
    for(i=0; i<texts_vectors[id]; i++){
        x=0.0;
        for(j=0;j<DOC;j++){
            if(sim_matrix[i][j]>x){
                nn_array[i]=j;
                max_array[i]=x=sim_matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prior to this there is the creation of the arrays and the data input into the `vector[i][j]`

I created the arrays using malloc :

```
int **vector = malloc(DOC * sizeof *vector);
for (i = 0; i < DOC; i++){
    vector[i] = malloc(MAXWORDS * sizeof **vector);
}
double **sim_matrix = malloc(PARTS * sizeof *sim_matrix);
for (i = 0; i < PARTS; i++)
    sim_matrix[i] = malloc(DOC * sizeof **sim_matrix);

int *list = malloc(WHOLE * sizeof(int));

int *nn_array = malloc(PARTS * sizeof(int));

double *max_array = malloc(PARTS * sizeof(double));

int *size_of = malloc(PARTS * sizeof(int));

double *n_max = malloc(procs * sizeof(double));

int *texts_vectors = malloc(procs * sizeof(int));

int *merger_one = malloc(MAXWORDS * sizeof(int));

int *merger_two = malloc(MAXWORDS * sizeof(int));

int *last_one = malloc(MAXWORDS * sizeof(int));

int *last_two = malloc(MAXWORDS * sizeof(int));
```

The line where the problem persists: `last_one[i]=vector[(node1*PARTS)+texts_vectors[node1]][i];/*SIGSEV ERROR*/` is also executed in the first part of the if-loop `if(n_max[node1]==n_max[node2]){` but in that case there is no error.

The only thing that feels a little suspicious about this problem is the `texts_vectors[i]` array which keeps counting the number of `vector[i][j]` type data that are currently inside the nodes. But even that i think i got it covered.

I really hope that somebody could have a look at this cause it is really frustrating and it needs to be done.

If you have a better idea of what is going on and want to take a look at the whole code, [i pasted it into a pastezone.](http://paste.debian.net/108343/) Cheers and thanks in advance.

EDIT:

As it turns out the value that i passed with the array `text_vectors` where exceeding the boundaries of the array. Since the value was giving the maximum value, for the actual last position in the array i should subtract 1.  So that was it, no segmentation fault in the serial gdb and ddd. However this program now it doesn't run for more than 2 nodes. If i execute it in 4> nodes it crashes.

Comment: I'm not sure you're creating the `vector` and `sim_matrix` properly. The lines should be:`int **vector = malloc(DOC * sizeof(int*));` and `for (i = 0; i < DOC; i++) vector[i] = malloc(MAXWORDS * sizeof(int);`, with the respective change done for `sim_matrix` line. If I understand correctly, `vector` and `sim_matrix` are 2D arrays of ints and doubles, respectively. At least for the `sim_matrix`, pointers to doubles (4 bytes) and doubles (8 bytes) are different sizes.  I don't think this will solve your problem, but I'm running late to something and I'll give your code a better look over later.

Comment: I would appreciate that. As for the allocation for the arrays i used this way for some time now with no major problems. I could quickly change it and check it. Thanks for your time

Comment: Oh god sorry about that last comment. I just realized I you're dereferencing yeah nothing wrong in the way of creating the 2-D arrays

Comment: This is a hell lot of a code and your paste link expires soon. This definitely runs against the good ways of asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 2):

This line has multiple errors in it:

```
MPI_Allgather(&texts_vectors,1,MPI_INT,texts_vectors,1,MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

First, you are providing a pointer to a pointer to the data as the first argument of the gather-to-all operation. Therefore the value transmitted by each rank is not the first element of `text_vectors` but rather the memory address of the data (or the lower half of the address on 64-bit little-endian LP64 systems).

Second, if you fix that by removing the address-off operator `&` from the beginning of the first argument, you will run into another problem. The MPI standard does not allow the source and destination buffers in `MPI_Allgather` to overlap. Some MPI implementations do not enforce that requirement and silently do *The Right Thing (TM)*. Some other MPI implementations will try to copy the data with `memcpy` and run into problems with the C library (`memcpy` does not allow overlapping buffers). And finally, some MPI implementations will give you a nice error message about overlapping buffers and terminate your program.

Since you are sending a single integer element, simply copy the value into a temporary variable and use its address as the first argument.

Comment: I did use a simple integer to pass the value, and also used `&texts_vectors[id] and for some reason i changed it. Thanks for pointing that out. Two sets of eyes is always better than one. Error still persistent though

Comment: `&texts_vectors[id]` is wrong too. It still points to a location that lies within the receive buffer and that's forbidden by the MPI standard. `MPI_Allgather` provides a special in-place mode that should be used instead - see [the documentation](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.6/man3/MPI_Allgather.3.php) (this one is from Open MPI but applies to MPICH too).

Comment: Perhaps, but for some executions it worked for me. Either way, i use a variable now, but the error is still there. Inside the `else-loop` and the `if(id==node1)` expression.I keep getting a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: It works for you because you use an old MPICH version. There is a similar problem in one of the programs included in SPEC MPI2007 so it cannot run on modern MPI implementations or on modern Linux systems. Anyway, you should probably use some parallel debugger to examine how your code works (doable with `printf` debugging too).